# Programming IDE on Transformer

Tags: applications, asus-eee-pad-transformer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to program on a Honeycomb tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11812/is-it-possible-to-program-on-a-honeycomb-tablet)

since Transformer has nice resolution (1280x800) and hardware keyboard I am wondering if I can install some programming IDE on it. Not just text books (they are all around the Market) but some serious programming application with syntax hilit, intellisense etc.

Any tips?