# Code/Program Java on Kindle Fire

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do development on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18111/how-can-i-do-development-on-my-android-device)

OK, so I've just got a new Kindle Fire (which I love), and I've been wondering:

**Can I develop Java programs on my Kindle?**

Is this even possible? Can a Gingerbread tablet do this?  I am looking for an offline solution.

*Note: This is not a programming question, so it would be off-topic on any other SE site*

Comment: Questions about development tools are arguably not off-topic on [SO], but you'd need to be more specific.  The duplicate should cover this though I think.

Comment: @MatthewRead: I edited the question to not be a duplicate. It is now specified towards Java, offline. Please consider reopening this question.

Comment: @Jae, the Java-centric answer that I'd give you is already represented in an answer to the linked question: Terminal IDE.  I'd suggest a tablet with Bluetooth, though, for the keyboard.